# Class has too many responsibilities but i can't think of other way to design it

Tags: c#, solid-principles

I have a method that logs something i want in the UI

```
class Log
{
     public static void Add(object text, bool isThread = false, int threadId = 0)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("[THREAD # " + threadId + "] " + text.ToString());
     }
}
```

and the WorkerThread class itself which uses that method.

```
     class WorkerThread
     {
         private int threadId;

         public WorkerThread(int _threadId)
         {
             threadId = _threadId;
         }

         private void InitializeBrowser()
         {
             // code that initializes the browser
         }

         private void GoToAmazonHome()
         {
             Log.Add("Going to amazon home", true, threadId);
             // code that goes to amazon home
         }

         private void SearchKeywordOnAmazon(string keyword)
         {
             Log.Add("Searching amazon for keyword " + keyword, true, threadId);
             // code that searches amazon for a keyword
         }

         private List<string> ScrapeTopUrls()
         {
             Log.Add("Scraping top urls", true, threadId); 
             // code that scrapes top urls
         }

         private void Start()
         {
              InitializeBrowser();
              GoToAmazonHome();
              ScrapeTopUrls("pogo");
         }
    }
```

So what i would like to do is make separate classes to take care of navigating through amazon and scraping top results.

I dont see how i can do that without makijng it confusing like having to pass in threadId in those functions also so they can call Log.Add with that threadId.

Comment: Each of the methods on `WorkerThread` look like some kind of Action to me.  You might be able to refactor those in to an actual `ApplicationAction` class, with `WorkerThread` doing the dispatch to the appropriate action.

Comment: Create classes who's sole responsibility is to perform their task (i.e TopUrlScraper, AmazonKeywordSearch, etc).  Abstract them to interfaces, and inject dependency through the constructor.  Then inside your methods, call the injected class.  That way your logic is separated, and this class' responsibility is to call the different classes and pass the threadId to the logger

Comment: Don't redesign your code because you read somewhere that something is a bad idea. Redesign your code because you have an identifiable problem writing or maintaining it. If encountering that problem makes you say "Oh, *now* I get what that SOLID Agile BBQ article was getting at", *that's* when you worry about Agile BBQ principles or whatever it is. That stuff should provide a framework for understanding the real problems you encounter in programming. "Single responsibility" is gibberish until you have enough experience to understand what they mean by it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the thread id just for the logging, you don't have to pass it as parameter.

There is a static property `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` that you can use. It will return your current thread's Id